# Where are zeroes coming from this program that prints the row-wise and column-wise sorted matrix in ascending order?

Tags: c++, sorting, debugging, matrix, heap

I'm trying to print the rowwise and columnwise sorted matrix elements in sorted order. I'm using a MIN-HEAP of size equal to that of given MATRIX's row count. I'm getting the desired output for all my cases. **Except that some zeroes**, occur in inbetween the desired output. I don't seem to find where these zeroes are actually inserted into the heap.

Here is the example of trial run: http://ideone.com/Ctmo91

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits.h>
using namespace std;

struct heapnode
{
    int element;
    int r;
    int c;
};
class heap
{
public:
    struct heapnode *harr;
    int heapsize;
    int capacity;

    heap(int n)
    {
        harr = new heapnode[n];
        heapsize = 0;
        capacity = n;
    }
    void minheapify(int i)
    {
        int smallest=i,lchild,rchild;
        while(1)
        {
            lchild = 2*i + 1;
            rchild = 2*i + 2;
            if(lchild<heapsize && harr[smallest].element > harr[lchild].element )
                smallest = lchild;
            if(rchild<heapsize && harr[smallest].element > harr[rchild].element)
                smallest = rchild;
            if(smallest!=i)
            {
                swap(harr[i],harr[smallest]);
                i = smallest;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    void buildheap(int n)
    {
        heapsize = n;
        for(int i=heapsize/2 -1;i>=0;i--)
            minheapify(i);
    }
};
void printSortedMatrix(int **arr,int m,int n)
{
    int k=m;
    int i,j;
    heap H(m);
    struct heapnode hr;
    int count =0;
    while(1)
    {
        //cout<<count<<endl;
        if(count < k-1)
        {
            //cout<<count<<" "<<k<<endl;
            H.harr[count] = {arr[count][0],count,0};
        }
        else
        {
            if(count==k-1)
            {
                H.harr[count] = {arr[count][0],count,0};
                H.buildheap(k);
            }
            if(H.harr[0].element==999)
                break;

            cout<<H.harr[0].element<<" ";

            hr = H.harr[0];
            if(hr.c==n)
                H.harr[0] = {999,0,0};
            else
                H.harr[0] = {arr[hr.r][hr.c+1],hr.r,hr.c+1};
            H.minheapify(0);
        }
        count++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
 {
    //code
    int t,N,**arr,i,j,M;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>M;
        N = M;
        arr = new int*[M];
        for(i=0;i<M;i++)
            arr[i] = new int[N];
        for(i=0;i<M;i++)
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                cin>>arr[i][j];
        printSortedMatrix(arr,M,N);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run this through valgrind. I'd say it is highly likely you're accessing outside your allocation boundaries and invoking undefined behavior. I also suggest you eliminate the first test and just use the second, when valgrinding this. It should be sufficient.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've tried checking for out of bounds access using CODEBLOCKS IDE debugger. I didn't find anything wrong. Would you re-suggest me to use valgrind again for this? and  I'm on windows :(

Comment: Hint: What is the range of values that `rchild` will have in `minheapify`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I'm initializing heapsize as **n** in  **buildheap**, so I would say ranges from 0 to heapsize-1 which is correct to my view. And rchild is 2*i + 2 because the first element in the heap is at 0th index of the array harr

Comment: `i`'s initial value in `buildheap` is `heapsize/2 - 1`.  What's `rchild` going to be in that case?

Comment: @WhozCraig    Should I delete the question? My problem is resolved. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the bug. I was actually pushing an element extra in each row.

```
if(hr.c==n)
    H.harr[0] = {999,0,0};
else
    H.harr[0] = {arr[hr.r][hr.c+1],hr.r,hr.c+1};
```

As one could notice, program is checking for column number to be **n**, while it actually ranges from **0** to **n-1**.

```
if(hr.c==n-1)              //The change
    H.harr[0] = {999,0,0};
else
    H.harr[0] = {arr[hr.r][hr.c+1],hr.r,hr.c+1};
```